# How to create a dummy window for messages only?

Tags: c++, winapi

Current code:

```
hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LEFT, // this is the default
                    L"MyWindow Class",  // the name of the class, as passed to the RegisterClass function
                    NULL, //  Title
                    0,    //  dwFlags, in our case this really doesn't matter
                    0,    //  X 
                    0,    //  Y 
                    0,    //  W 
                    0,    //  H 
                    HWND_MESSAGE , //the most important flag! Creates a message-only window
                    0,    //  hMenu 
                    0 ,   //  hInstance 
                    0     //  lpParam 
);
```

The `hwnd` returned is null, I dont understand how to define the `hInstance` and if I really need it for this usecase.

Comment: [What is the HINSTANCE passed to CreateWindow and RegisterClass used for?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050418-59/?p=35873)

Comment: When `CreateWindowEx()` fails, use `GetLastError()` to find out why. But, did you successfully register the `"MyWindow Class"` class name with `RegisterClass/Ex()` before calling `CreateWindowEx()`? You need to use the same `HINSTANCE` for registration and creation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I had an error in the registration of the class, however, how do i find the `hwnd` of this window from another program? I set a title to the created window and tried to search her `hwnd` with `FindWindow`, but it does not find it.

Comment: @Razec "*I had an error in the registration of the class*" - then why did you proceed to try to create the window? "*how do i find the `hwnd` of this window from another program?*" - did you [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows)? "*To find message-only windows, specify `HWND_MESSAGE` in the `hwndParent` parameter of the `FindWindowEx` function. In addition, `FindWindowEx` searches message-only windows as well as top-level windows if both the `hwndParent` and `hwndChildAfter` parameters are NULL.*"